# How to write the contents of a dictionary to a MessageBox

Tags: vb.net, dictionary

In VB.NET I want to write the contents of a dictionary to a message box.

The dictionary is rather basic

```
    Dim x As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Users)
    x.Add("1", New Users("1", "Simon"))
```

The user class contains 2 attributes, user ID (Integer) and Username (String).

I am struggling to write the dictionary contents. I would like to write each dictionary entry to a string but i am having no success as I keep getting the error message:

> Argument 'Prompt' cannot be converted to type 'String'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing a string where you specified an integer:

Fix:

```
Dim x As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Users)
x.Add(1, New Users(1, "Simon"))
```

Then to show the contents:

```
Dim sb As New StringBuilder
For Each item As KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Users) In x
  sb.AppendLine(item.Key & ") " & item.Value.ToString)
Next
MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString())
```

Your Users class would need to override the `ToString` function or change the `ToString` call to the property in Users that shows the user's name.

Update to Users class:

```
Public Class Users
  Private _p1 As Integer
  Private _p2 As String

  Sub New(ByVal p1 As Integer, ByVal p2 As String)
    _p1 = p1
    _p2 = p2
  End Sub

  Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
    Return _p2
  End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. All seems to be working well, but it does not output the class contents (1, Simon) but just the Class name. Im guessing this is to do with needing to override the ToString function? My class is as follows Class Users

    Private _p1 As String
    Private _p2 As String

    Sub New(ByVal p1 As String, ByVal p2 As String)
        ' TODO: Complete member initialization 
        _p1 = p1
        _p2 = p2
    End Sub

End Class

Comment: @user1139093 I updated the answer.  You should strongly consider giving your variables better names.  p1 and p2 do not convey anything.  Also, I changed p1 to an integer.  If it needs to be a string, then you need to change your dictionary to be (Of String, String) instead of integer.

Comment: Again, thank you for the response. I am just starting out trying to get to grips with it all so i will most definitely rename my variables with better names. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 1):

Here you go.

```
        Dim sbMessage As New System.Text.StringBuilder(500)

        For Each wKey As Integer In x.Keys
            sbMessage.Append("Key = ").Append(wKey).Append(", Value = ").Append(x.Item(wKey).ToString()).AppendLine()
        Next
        MessageBox.Show(sbMessage.ToString)
```

To make this useful, you will need to override the ToString method in the Users class. For example, assuming that there is an ID and a name in this class:

```
Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
    Dim sbText As New System.Text.StringBuilder(500)

    sbText.Append("ID = ").Append(Me.Id).Append(", Name = ").Append(Me.Name)

    Return sbText.ToString
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

```
For Each kvp As KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Users) In x
            Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", _
                kvp.Key, kvp.Value)
        Next kvp
```

Something like that, bearing in mind that your Value will be a Users object, and that as @LarsTech said, you should pass in an integer instead of a string into the Dictionary